# Convert Spring MVC project to JAX-RS

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jax-rs

I'm trying to do a project with JAX-RS, Spring, Hibernate, Maven and JPA. I'm following this [article](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/sample-projects/school-addmission-system.html) as reference. This project is in Spring MVC. I'm very new to Spring MVC. I have tried to convert it to JAX-RS. What are the important changes I have to do with this?

The main change I noticed that in Spring MVC we use like this: `@RequestMapping("/accounts/{username}")`.

But in JAX-RS we use like this. `@Path("/accounts/{username}")`

Therefore If I do the changes like this, what are the other key changes we have to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic thing you need to do in order to port the Spring MVC controllers to JAX-RS controllers, is to provide and integration between Spring and your JAX-RS provider. One way to do that is to make the appropriate changes to `web.xml`.

Assuming you are using Jersey 2.x and Spring 3.x, the `web.xml` would look like:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <module-name>helloworld-spring</module-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>some.package.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Then `MyApplication` would look like:

```
package some.package;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.RequestContextFilter;


public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {


    public MyApplication () {
        register(RequestContextFilter.class);
        register(JerseyResource.class);
        register(SpringSingletonResource.class);
        register(SpringRequestResource.class);
        register(CustomExceptionMapper.class);
    }
}
```

You will also need the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

besides the other Spring 3 and Jersey 2 dependencies.

Once you get that out of the way, you can start transforming the controllers.

For example:

```
@Path("admin")
@Component
public class AdminController {

        @Autowired
        private SchoolService service;


        @Path("load-home-page")
        @GET
        public String loadHomePage(Map model){
           return "admin/index";
        }

        //the rest of the code accordingly
}
```

The documentation for Spring-Jersey integration is [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html) while a complete example can be found [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.10.1/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp).

Personally I would go the Spring MVC route instead of Jersey if you really don't have a compelling reason to choose Jersey over Spring MVC.

Comment: Why we need `MyApplication`? When I create the `MYApplication`, It shows some error. Do we need additional dependencies to it?

Comment: When I put these code into `MyApplication` It shows curly red underlines. `register(JerseyResource.class);
        register(SpringSingletonResource.class);
        register(SpringRequestResource.class);
        register(CustomExceptionMapper.class); `

Comment: Does `ResourceConfig` exist on your classpath?

Comment: No, How do I add it? I try to add maven dependency, It didn't work.

Comment: Have you checked out https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html?